# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre HashMap y Hashtable en JAVA?

Tags: java

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre `HashMap` y `Hashtable`? Según lo que se de estructuras de datos vendría a ser lo mismo conceptualmente, pero en **Java** ¿cual sería la diferencia?

¿Cuál es más recomendado para ser usado en aplicaciones que utilicen `Threads`?

Comment: Para tu última pregunta: *¿Cuál es más recomendado para ser usado en aplicaciones que utilicen hilos (traducción de threads)?*, la respuesta es **NINGUNA**, utiliza [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) que soporta sincronización de manera más correcta que `Hashtable`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Sincronización

La principal diferencia entre uno y otro es la sincronización interna del objeto.

Para aplicaciones multi-hilo es preferible elegir [`Hashtable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) sobre [`HashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), que no tiene sincronización.

Debes tener en cuenta, sin embargo, que `HashTable` ofrece sincronización en los métodos de acceso y mutación, que impedirán que dos hilos diferentes agreguen o eliminen de manera concurrente de la lista, pero **hay operaciones típicas de una aplicación multi-hilo que van a requerir de sincronización externa**.

Un caso común es el de *verificar y agregar*, que no es más que buscar si una llave existe en la lista, y si no agregarla. No hay manera de realizar esto en una operación atómica utilizando `Hashtable` ni `HashMap`.

```
synchronized(myMap) {
    if (!myMap.containsKey("tomato"))
        myMap.put("tomato", "red");
}
```

La iteración sobre entradas de `Hashtable` tampoco es *thread-safe*, a menos que prevengas que la lista sea modificada con sincronización adicional:

Hay Implementaciones de la Interface [`ConcurrentMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) (por ejemplo [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)) que resuelven algunos de estos problemas al incluir semántica *verificar luego actuar* que es *thread-safe*, por ejemplo

```
ConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent(key, value);
```

### Llaves o valores null

Otra diferencia importante es que `Hashtable` no permite llaves o valores `null`, mientras que `HashMap` permite una llave y cualquier vantidad de valores `null`.

### Orden de iteración

Una de las subclases de `HashMap`es [`LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) , que te sirve en el caso que requieras un orden de iteración predecible (que por defecto es el orden de inserción). Puedes fácilmente cambiar tu declaración de `HashMap` por `LinkedHashMap`.

> Con información de [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40471/255257)

Comment: Recuerda agregar las fuentes de tu respuesta que en este caso es una combinación de http://stackoverflow.com/a/41454/2177143 y http://stackoverflow.com/a/40878/2177143

Answer (score 4):

La tipica pregunta de entrevista,

HashTable es una estructura de datos un poco vieja, si bien es cierto todo lo que comentan sobre la sincronizacion y que no permite un null como key o value, creo que vale la pena mencionar que su linea de jerarquia es diferente a la de un mapa ya que HastTable extiende a Dictionary otra estrucura de datos un poco pasada de moda, mientras que un HashMap extiende a AbstractMap pero ambas implementan a Map.

Hay un metodo en la clase Collections (Helper Class), para crear mapas sincronizados que nos pueden ayudar a reemplazar el uso de HashTables en nuestros programas.

```
 Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap(...));
```

Tambien se puede lograr la sincronizacion con un bloque sincronziado

```
 synchronized(myMap) { }
```

Fuente: Java Doc Java - grepcode.com

Para entender un poco mejor como funcionan estos objetos recomiendo ampliamente leer el codigo fuente de los mismos:

HashMap source code:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashMap.java

HashTable source code: 
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Hashtable.java#Hashtable

Si quieres usar un mapa sincronizado para una applicacion Multi-Threading tambien existe este objecto en el paquete de concurrencia de java.util que te puede ser de bastante utilidad.

```
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Respuesta adaptada de : [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable/40878#40878)

Hay varias diferencias entre los dos:

1. [`Hashtable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) es sincronizado, [`HashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) no. En tu caso debes usar `Hashtable` ya que tu aplicación es multihilos según mencionas.
2. `Hashtable` no permite `null` como *key* o *value*.  `HashMap` solo permite un único *key* que sea `null` y no hay restricciones para usar `null`  en todos los *values* que desees.
3. Una de las subclases de `HashMap` es [`LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), así que si quisieras un orden predecible al iterarlo puedes cambiar `HashMap` por `LinkedHashMap`. `Hashtable` no tiene ninguna subclase parecida.