# Clase similar a HashMap que aporte get(int index) en Java

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

Busco una clase de Java que me permita almacenar dos variables del tipo que sea uniendolas, pero que además me permita acceder a ellas de una forma ascendente/descendente o por índice.

Buscando encontré la clase HashMap, que cumple lo primero que busco, pero a la hora de acceder a los datos que contiene, no me vale el método get(Object key) que aporta, ya que desconozco los datos que almacena este objeto.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Contexto:

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa sobre paradas de autobuses. Estaba buscando una forma de emparejar la linea de la parada con los minutos restantes (hasta que el bus llegara a esta), entonces mi código es el siguiente:

```
//Crea una nueva parada
EMTParada parada= new EMTParada();
    //Establece el nombre de la parada (código no necesario )
    parada.setStopName(nomParada);
    //Lectura de paradas (datos obtenidos desde un HTML, clase Document)
    for(Element a: busLineList.select("li")){
     // A la izquierda agrego el número de la linea y a la derecha los minutos restantes
        parada.setLinea(Integer.parseInt(a.getElementsByAttribute("title").text()),a.select("span.minutos"+"[0-9]").text());
    }
```

Método `setLinea();`

```
private HashMap linea= new HashMap<Integer,String>();

public void setLinea(int num, String string) {
    linea.put(num,string);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema principal es que la clase `HashMap` no preserva el orden de inserción por lo que no puedes acceder por indice de forma directa vía índice:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Puedes usar en su lugar `[LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)' que garantiza un orden de iteración predecible y te permite recorrer la lista en orden pero, igualmente, no permite el acceso por índice.

**Soluciones si se requiere de acceso índice:**

Una posible solución es pasar los valores (no claves) a una lista:

```
List keys = new ArrayList(map.keySet());
for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
    Object obj = keys.get(i);
    // do stuff here
}
```

o a un array:

```
public Object getElementByIndex(LinkedHashMap map,int index){
    return map.get( (map.keySet().toArray())[ index ] );
}
```

pero en ambos casos el resultado es poco óptimo.

Una tercera **alternativa más correcta** y elegante es crear una clase `Pair` y crear una lista de objetos de esta lista. De este modo puedes acceder por índice a cada par de valores.

Clase Pair:

```
public class Pair<L,R> {
    private L l;
    private R r;
    public Pair(L l, R r){
        this.l = l;
        this.r = r;
    }
    public L getL(){ return l; }
    public R getR(){ return r; }
    public void setL(L l){ this.l = l; }
    public void setR(R r){ this.r = r; }
}
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>> map = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>();
map.add(new Pair("Hello", 10));
map.add(new Pair("World", 20));

Pair<String, Integer> hello = map.get(0);
System.out.println("Hello string: " + hello.getL());
System.out.println("Hello integer: " + hello.getR());
```

salida:

```
Hello string: Hello
Hello integer: 10
```

Comment: Me gusta, sobre la primera solución desconocía la existencia del método `map.keySet()`, entiendo que devuelve un conjunto de claves que establezco en el map a la hora de introducir valores. Con respecto a la clase `Pair`, ¿podría decir que lo que hace es emparejar las dos variables String e Integer, y gracias a que lo declaramos como una lista, podemos acceder por indice?

Comment: @JD0001 Efectivamente, en este caso de ejemplo las he definido como String e Integer pero la clase las implemente como Generics, es decir, que puedes declarar el par de clases que requieras en cada momento.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo que utilices HashTable. Por ejemplo imagínate que creamos un objeto HashTable:

```
Hashtable<String,String> contadores = new Hashtable();
```

Por ejemplo yo en este caso creo un HashTable para almacenar los datos que leo de un fichero XML

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        File fichero = new File("DescargaContadores.xml");
        Document document = (Document) builder.build(fichero);
        Element rootElement = document.getRootElement();
        List listaMeter = rootElement.getChildren("Meter");
        System.out.println("Leyendo XML Contadores...");
        for(int i=0;i<listaMeter.size();i++){
            //Se obtiene el elemento MeterNumber
            Element meterNumber = (Element) listaMeter.get(i);
            Element situation = (Element) listaMeter.get(i);
            Element baja = (Element) listaMeter.get(i);

            //Se comprueba que no esté dado de baja
            if(baja.getChildTextTrim("Baja").equals("0") && !meterNumber.getChildTextTrim("Situation").isEmpty()){
                //Ahora se guardan los datos en los String
                numSerie = meterNumber.getChildTextTrim("MeterNumber");
                calle = situation.getChildTextTrim("Situation");

                //Ahora se meten en el HashTable
                contadores.put(numSerie, calle);
            }
        }
```

Bueno a partir de la comprobación, para añadir la clave,valor al HashTable introduzco `contadores.put(numSerie,calle`);

Después para verificar que se ha llenado el HashTable, lo único que hago es recorrerlo:

```
Enumeration e = contadores.keys();
        Object clave;
        Object valor;
        while(e.hasMoreElements()){
            clave = e.nextElement();
            valor = contadores.get(clave);
            System.out.println(clave+"-"+valor);//Mostramos la información
        }
```

Espero que mi aportación te sirva. No realizo un get(i), y me coge igual los valores. Hay muchas formas de coger un objeto de una **Collection** , y esta es otra manera.

Un Saludo.

Comment: Hola barraca. ¿Qué ofrece `Hashtable` que no tiene ya `HashMap`? ¿Y como resuelve el problema de ordenar los elementos?

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta! Casualmente el tema va sobre eso, estaba leyendo información desde un HTML. Muy interesante la clase `Enumeration`, desconocia de su existencia y que se podía aplicar a un map de esta manera. Desgraciadamente donde yo estudio se le ha dado muy poca importancia a las colecciones y ando bastante perdido. Saludos! –

Comment: A nivel de API de uso son iguales. Las únicas diferencias es que `Hashtable` es sincronizado y no admite valores `null` como clave: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1234/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-hashmap-y-hashtable-en-java

Comment: De nada, gracias también a la respuesta sobre las diferencias de HashMap y HashTable, nunca me había fijado en las diferencias entre una Collection y otra.

Answer (score 0):

creo que mi solución es más sencilla. Si necesitas que dos valores estén relacionados de alguna manera y guardarlos en una colección en memoria, lo mejor es que crees una clase con dos propiedades que representen los dos valores que quieras almacenar y luego ya usar la colección que más te convenga para tu proceso (listas, mapas, pilas...).

Creo que esto es más sencillo, lo puedes implementar con muy poco código, y quedará más legible.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Probaré todas las alternativas que me estáis ofreciendo, muchas gracias por tu aporte!

Comment: De nada, recuerda marcar la que consideres que te ha ayudado más y se adapta mejor a la resolución del problema.